# ASP.NET MVC Anti Forgery Token - Apps in same IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, antiforgerytoken, web-farm

I have more than one app running in a IIS and I get the following error:

> The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is
>   hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running
>   the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the 
>   configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys.

That occurs when I open a web app, for example http://localhost:90 and logging into it. Later, I open a second tab (http://localhost:91) and logging into the web app. After that, I return to the first tab and press Log Off (or any other post to any other form) and I get the error.

- There isn't more than one AntiForgeryToken in the same views
- I tried to configure individual MachineKeys in the web apps and I couldn't resolve it (from the IIS and from the web.config too).

Comment: Is it the same web application on both ports?

Comment: Differents web applications in differents ports

Comment: I tried to reproduce it, but what happened was that if I logged out from one application, I was automatically logged out from the other one. Cookies are per domain, so for example, if you created a custom cookie in http://localhost:90, this will be available in http://localhost:91 as well.My guess is that session cookies get mixed between applications.

Comment: You have different application pool for each application? And deploy them to IIS or run the apps from VS? You configure different Machine Keys for each app ?

Comment: Anyway, thanks you for ur help. I find that the problem could be caused by the shared cookies as you say.

Comment: I run the apps in IIS. They have the same Machine Key and that's probably why I didn't get the error as in your scenario.

Comment: I run the apps in IIS but I configure individual machine keys for each app